# How to aggregate and limit the documents based on an array inside of an object from the req.body?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

First of all, I'm Brazilian and my English (also my programming) are not that god but I will try to do my best here (desperate times call for... you know.).

Well, I'm just trying to create an order.

I'm passing through the body an object that consists of the seller, the customer, and an array with the typeProduct ids (which I'm going to use to bring all the itemProducts that matches it) and the quantity that I need to limit these products aggregated by these IDs

[The limit that I want to pass in each one is on "qty"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP8lr.jpg)

[i just cant go on from here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuAgT.jpg)

Then I just separate the ids...
...
[and the result returns all matched objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQWjY.jpg)

I just need a way to aggregate this objects limiting the quantity of the itemObjects based on the value of the 'qty.'

I tried a lot of crazy stuff, even:

```
**
req.body.typeProducts.forEach(item){
 const dbItemProducts = await item.find(
      {
         $and: [
        {
            'typeProduct': item.typeProductId,
         },
         {
             isAvailable: { $eq: true },
          },
        ],
       },
    ).limit(item.qty);
}**

...of course, and find() inside a foreach didn't work.
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem, you want to limit the quantity so that you dont sell more than you have, is that the idea?

Comment: You want to create an order, for example John sold 3 apples to Mary, why do you want to aggregate the 3 apples?

Comment: I have an array of objects with mango, orange, pineapple... all mixed up coming from the db. then the costumer wants 3 apples, 2 pineapples, 10 oranges (that's  is the limit I'm talking about)... but the thing is that the 'qty' is a a property from the array passed through the body (look the first image) and I don't know how to apply it to the quantity OF EACH OBJECT i want.

Comment: Vamos em português mesmo rsrs, na primeira imagem você está mandando um POST para `orders/create`, então você está criando uma ordem certo? Na segunda imagem voce está selecionando de `ItemProduct` onde o produto estiver na lista. ItemProduct é a ordem? A terceira imagem é o resultado, está correto, todos eles tem um dos 2 produtos que você passou...